# Wordpress Plugin Max Posts

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have a match plugin for wordpress. In the backend I can register matches. These matches are then displayed on the home page with a shortcode. Currently, all matches are displayed but I would like to see only the 5 newest ones.

```
Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZLKZj
```

Website: http://ayb-esports.com

I want only the newest matches on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided doesnt build correctly. Raw PHP is output instead of the dynamic content. However, the issue should be in the wordpress query `'posts_per_page' => -1` will return everything, change this to 5

Comment: I know because its just PHP code from my plugin :) maybe i need to edit something in this code.